# Force computed column to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table created with [TankNumId] as a computed column.

How can I make the data type be forced to int.  It keeps setting as nvarchar, which is the data type of the column [TankNum].

The values in [TankNum] column are `100-1, 100-2 100-3, etc`.  Hence why I am using the computed column to convert the '-' to '.' so that it can be a valid int in the [TankNumId] column.  Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTank9](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TankNumId]  AS (replace([TankNum],'-','.' )) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[TankNum] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[CompanyName] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Ft] [float] NULL,
[Inch] [float] NULL,
[HFt] [smallint] NULL,
[HIn] [smallint] NULL,
[HFx] [smallint] NULL,
[GaPt] [char](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTank9] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[TankNumId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: `100.1` isnt an integer neither

Comment: Ok are you ever going to do math on tankNumID?  If not store it as nvarchar(X).  no reason to store a value as a number JUST becaue it looks like a number.  you wouldn't want to store zipcode as a numeric or telephone.  Why?  Becuase you'll never do math on them.  If no math, store it as a string; unless it's a date.  Dates always are dates.  If you are going to do math on it, store it is number(X,Y) with the precision and scale needed to support your specific data.  Float/Double is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I don't see why you want int or any numeric value in the first place nvarchar seems the right datatype to me.

Answer (score 1):

**[replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)** function receive `nvarchar` and return `nvarchar`

You need CAST or CONVERT your result to float because `100.1` isnt integer

```
SELECT CAST(YourVarcharCol AS float) FROM Table
SELECT CONVERT(float, YourVarcharCol) FROM Table
```

Comment: no... not float... use number(10,2) (or whatever precision,scale is needed) float & double will screw with those decimal values which I think have specific desired precision.

Comment: Can I create a new table so that it is casted to this beforehand?